# On my Xiaomi, does the checkmark at "restrict data usage" mean "only allow" or "do not allow"

Tags: settings

On my Xiaomi, does the checkmark at "restrict data usage" mean "only allow" or "do not allow"? Each of the two SIM and WLAN has the possibility of a checkmark, but what sense should I view the choice?

Answer (score 0):

When checked, restrict usage data means that the application can not use the internet when using simcard.